# Adding items to a collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem adding entities to a collection.

```
public void SaveNotificationUsergroups(int bookingobjectID, int[] NotificationUsergroups)
    {

        BookingObject bo = _entities.BookingObjectSet.Where(b => b.BookingObjectID == bookingobjectID).First();

        bo.UsergroupsBookingNotifications.Load();

        int _currentUsergroupID;

        for (int i = 0; i < NotificationUsergroups.Count(); i++)
        {
            _currentUsergroupID = NotificationUsergroups[i];

            bo.UsergroupsBookingNotifications.Add(_entities.UsergroupSet.Where(ug => ug.UsergroupID == _currentUsergroupID).First();
        }

        _entities.SaveChanges();

    }
```

I get an error on:

```
bo.UsergroupsBookingNotifications.Add(_entities.UsergroupSet.Where(ug => ug.UsergroupID == _currentUsergroupID).First();
```

that is:

> cannot convert from
>   'BookingSystem.Data.Models.Usergroup'
>   to
>   'BookingSystem.Data.Models.UsergroupsBookingNotifications'

In the database UsergroupsBookingNotifications has "int BookingObjectID" and "int UsergroupID"

whats needed to do?

/M

EDIT:

Tables:

Usergroups  <---> UsergroupsBookingNotifications <--> Bookings

Comment: The paranetheses on that line doesn't match up, so that can't be the code that you are using. What does the actual code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting this error is because bo.UsergroupsBookingNotifications is a collection of UsergroupsBookingNotifications and you are trying to add a Usergroup object to it.

This:

```
_entities.UsergroupSet.Where(ug => ug.UsergroupID == _currentUsergroupID).First();
```

will return a Usergroup object.

With out seeing the rest of you object model it's a bit hard to help but this might be what you are looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NotificationUsergroups.Count(); i++)
{
    _currentUsergroupID = NotificationUsergroups[i];

    // Make a new UsergroupsBookingNotifications object
    UsergroupsBookingNotifications notify = new UsergroupsBookingNotifications();

    // Add the bookobject and usergroup
    notify.BookingObject = bo;
    notify.Usergroup = _entities.UsergroupSet.Where(ug => ug.UsergroupID == _currentUsergroupID).First();

    // Add the collection.
    bo.UsergroupsBookingNotifications.Add(notify);
}
```

Like I said it's a bit hard to help without some more info, but that might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can't add a UserGroup into a UsergroupsBookingNofication.  I don't know for sure because I don't know what your relationships are.